# Capture label click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jqxWidgets The tree menu and cannot seem to find a way to capture the click event of a label in jquery. Is there a way to capture this label in jquery for processing? I have included the relevant snippet of code and would appreciate your expert advice. Many thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var source = [
    { label: "Weekly Reports", expanded: false, items: [
        { label: "Intake" },
        { label: "Retrieval", selected: false },
        { label: "Returns", selected: false }
    ]
    },
    /*{ label: "Item 2" },
    { label: "Item 3" },*/
    { label: "Monthly Reports", items: [
        { label: "Item 4.1" },
        { label: "Item 4.2" }
    ]
    },
    /*{ label: "Item 5" },
    { label: "Item 6" },
    { label: "Item 7" }*/
    { label: "Movement Reports", items: [
        { label: "Item 4.1" },
        { label: "Item 4.2" }
    ]
    },
     { label: "Destruction Reports", items: [
        { label: "Item 4.1" },
        { label: "Item 4.2" }
    ]
    },
];
  var theme = "";
  // Create jqxTree
  $("#jqxTree").jqxTree({ source:source, theme: theme });

  // Create jqxExpander
  $("#jqxExpander").jqxExpander({  showArrow: false, toggleMode: "none", width: "262px", height: "auto", theme: theme });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Show the actual HTML that this renders and how you are hooking up your event handler.

Comment: There is no rendered html. The tree is populated using the posted code. If i use firebug, this is the code is produced when i select element and click: <div style="display: inline-block;" class="jqx-rc-all draggable jqx-tree-item jqx-item">Intake</div>

Comment: If there is no rendered HTML, how does anyone see anything?

Comment: I have checked view source in ff and there is definately no rendered html for the menu.

Comment: I have posted the complete js that makes up the menu tree. Thanks

Comment: Source = what is loaded with the page. Rendered = what the code injects when it runs. View source will never show rendered HTML. You need to use the element inspector.

Comment: In that case, it is the code i posted in reply to your earlier comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jqxTree has a built in callback for the `select` event. You can capture this event and retrieve the label that was clicked like so:

```
$('#jqxTree').on('select',function (event){
    var args = event.args;
    var item = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);
    var label = item.label; 
});
```